# Scale Instances by Proximity to Curve points with Radius Attr

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves

I'm using curve as a **proximity** object for scaling **scattered dots**, but i'm want to use the **Radius attribute** of the curve also to manipulate scale of dots

[image]

[image]

What i want:

[image]

Comment: you will attract more people if you provide a blend file so we don't have to rebuild it manually...

Comment: You already have a small error here at the beginning: You capture the radius of the points in the *Spline* domain... And the problem is actually not to get the value for the radius, but much more the question how exactly this should then be utilized.

Comment: Probably distance should subtract radius, to make it the distance to the geometry the curve would produce if it was converted to mesh with default curve circle as a profile. Would be a signed distance to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly You should use **Map Range Node** with **Proximity Node** ***always***, because this is the only way to manipulate the distance value.

Secondly you need to use **Sample Nearest Vertex** with **Sample Index Node** (aka transfer attribute).

[image]